# поиск символа в регулярном выражени

Tags: регулярные-выражения, kotlin

```
package ru.site

fun main() {

 var text: String = "Hello World!"

 //если символ l есть
 if(text.matches("[l]".toRegex())) {
  println("yes")
 } else {
  println("no")
 }

 var counter: Int = 0

 //колличество вхождений символа l
 text.forEach {
  if(text.matches("[l]".toRegex())) {
   counter++
  }
 }

 println(counter)

}
```

> no
>
> 0

Подскажите, почему не находится символ **l**? Спасибо.

Comment: Метод `matches` требует совпадения целой строки. Используйте `find` / `containsMatchIn`.

Comment: Потому что строка “Hello World” не соответствует строке “l”. Именно это вы проверяете в условиях, а совсем не то, что написано в комментариях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `matches` требует совпадения целой строки.

Используйте [`Regex.find`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find.html) / [`Regex.containsMatchIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/contains-match-in.html) для поиска *частичных* совпадений в строке и [`Regex.findall`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html) для поиска всех вхождений.

[Демо онлайн](https://rextester.com/FLA79699):

```
var text: String = "Hello World!"
var regx: Regex = "l".toRegex()

//если символ l есть
if(regx.containsMatchIn(text)) {
  println("yes")
} else {
  println("no")
}
// считаем кол-во совпадений
var counter: Int = regx.findAll(text).count()
println(counter)
```

Результат

```
yes
3
```